# Trying to call a function on an object

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, oop

It would probably be easiest if I showed you my code first:

```
def use(self):
    target = self.requestTarget()
    target = str(target)
    exec(self.whatDoes+"("+target+")")
```

`self.requestTarget` returns `player`, an object. `self.whatDoes` is `"learnAttack"`. `learnAttack()` takes an object as its argument, and append an item to a list the target has.
When I run this code, I get the error:

```
learnAttack(<character object at 0x7fda68acf1d0>)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Admittedly, I could have coded this better, but I have a whole framework set up and changing this code would involve a lot of work that I am too lazy to do.

And sorry for using `exec()`.

Comment: what do you want to pass to your routine? and `str` on an object is likely to return that kind of output unless you define the `__str__` method.

Comment: why exactly are you using `exec` for this?

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard XY-problem, again.

Comment: Make `self.whatDoes = learnAttack` (the function, not the string).  Then `self.whatDoes(target)` is equivalent to `learnAttack(target)`

Comment: you should create dictionary `functions["learnAttack"] = learnAttack` and then you don't need `exec()` but `functions[self.whatDoes](target)`. And then you don't have to convert `target` into `string` so you will have no problem with `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I would do that, but the way the code is structured, then it would not be able to request different targets every time it's used. The code here tries to do that with an exec statement.

Answer (score 1):

99.99 times out of 100, `exec` / `eval` are the wrong solution.

Python functions (as well as methods, classes and modules FWIW) are objects, so if you can make `self.whatDoes` point to a function (or method or any callable object) then you don't need `exec` nor `eval` - you can just apply the call operator with expected arguments, ie :

```
def fun(obj):
    print(obj)

class Whatever(object):
    pass

w = whatever()
w.whatDoes = fun

w.whatDoes(42)
```

If you need `whatDoes` to be a string, then build a `dict` of allowed function names -> functions and lookup that dict:

```
def fun(obj):
    print(obj)

FUNCTIONS = {
    "fun": fun,
    # etc
}

class Whatever(object):
    def requestTarget(self):
        return 42

    def use(self):
        target = self.requestTarget()
        func =  FUNCTIONS[self.whatDoes]
        return func(target)

w = Whatever()
w.whatDoes = "fun"
w.use()
```

Oh and yes, if "whatDoes" is supposed to be the name of method of your class, you can just use `getattr(obj,name)`

Answer (score 0):

Solution: replace `exec(self.whatDoes+"("+target+")")` with `exec(self.whatDoes+"(target)")` and remove the line `target = str(target)`

The problem here is that when you reach the line `target = str(target)`, what happens is that the variable target becomes the string `"<character object at 0x7fda68acf1d0>"`. It does not then still refer to the original object, but instead just to that string, which is just a string. Then, when your program gets to `exec(self.whatDoes+"("+target+")")`, which then is executed as `learnAttack(<character object at 0x7fda68acf1d0>)`, which causes an obvious syntax error, as running that would cause an error anywhere. With the fix suggested, it then executes `learnAttack(target)` with target still referring to the object.

Comment: well ideally, but this chap says he would rather not change other things, so this is a solution at least

Answer (score -1):

Use eval to create the function first and invoke it.

```
 def use(self):
   target = self.requestTarget()
   target = str(target)
   func = eval(self.whatDoes)
   func(target)
```